# Round number down to the next 1000 in python

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

can somebody tell me how i can round down to the nearest thousand. So far I tried it with math.round(), the truncate function but i couldn't find my math skills to work out for me. As a example for some people I want that 4520 ends up in beeing 4000.

Comment: `int(x/1000)*1000`?

Comment: 4000 is not the **nearest** thousand of 4520, this would be 5000

Comment: @mozway - "how i can round *down* to the nearest thousand"

Comment: @not_speshal fair enough (but a duplicate in both cases) :p

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can do

```
print((number // 1000)*1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

**just a thought**

> Why not do it the traditional way?!

```
deprecate_vals = 3 
val = 4520

val = int(val/(10**deprecate_vals)) * (10**deprecate_vals)
print(val)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can divide by 1000 before rounding and then multiply by 1000.

```
invalue = 4320
outvalue = 1000 * round(invalue/1000)
print("invalue: ",invalue)
print("rounded value: ",outvalue)
```

output

```
invalue:  4320
rounded value:  4000
```

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple way to do it.

You can get the digit for the thousand by using the division (// mean without remaining, so you don't get 4,52 but 4)

```py
x = 4520
rounded_x = (x//1000) * 1000
```

You can also use the remaining of the division with the modulo operator and remove it to the value :

```py
x = 4520
rounded_x = x - (x%1000)
```